# REST API for multiple actions on a file

Tags: api, rest

This is continuation of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645744/how-to-design-a-restful-api-for-a-media-analysis-engine) on how to design a REST API for a media analysis server. As per Derrel's answer, in my current design I start the analysis of a media file using a `POST /facerecognition/analysisrequests?profileId=33` which specifies that profile ID 33 (previously created on the server by another POST) should be used.

I have two short questions:

1. How can I extend this approach to have multiple analysis requests on the same file, e.g. perform both face recognition, text detection, and ad detection on the given file? Is using a binary coding (e.g. each bit signifies an analysis) and e.g. doing `POST http:[server URL]/00000011/analysisrequests?profileId=33` a good idea?
2. Is using a server side DB (e.g. mySQL) the best way to keep track of all the profile and process IDs?

Thanks,

C

Comment: One easy solution to (1) would be to infer the tasks to be performed from the profile document. Then, `POST [server URL]/analysis/profileId=33` would be enough. The downside of this is that the task info is not lost in the URL. Would this be a big problem with load balancers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making more complete use of [HTTP POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5).  Make all POST requests against the same URI: `/analysisrequest`.  Use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to send the parameters.

So:

```
Host: yourserver.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 73
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

face_recognition=true&text_detection=true&ad_detection=true&profile_id=33
```

`multipart/form-data` would also allow you to send the file being analyzed in the same request as the operations to perform on the file, assuming that's a desired scenario.  With the added advantage that you ought to be able to use the exact same API end-point for both HTML forms and your REST API.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put the types of analysis requested as parameters, rather than as part of the path.  They could be POST parameters in the body of the request, or specified in the URL list profileId.  Example:  `POST http://server/analysisrequest?profileId=33&analysisType=faceRecognition&analysisType=textDetection`.  It's perfectly ok to submit multiple values for a parameter.

You could submit the binary encoding of the analysis type, but spelling it out is a lot more clear and self-documenting.  The binary encoding is a bit fragile when adding a new analysis type as well;  adding a new digit would affect the urls all requests, even those that don't use the new type.

A server side database is typical for this kind of web application and it's probably a good solution.  You might also want to consider an in-process SQL database solution like [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) to avoid the complexity of a separate database process.